# Why I need to press F9 everytime I want to choose between two OS?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a dual boot in my laptop. I have Ubuntu and Windows installed. But whenever I boot my laptop, I have to press F9 to get the menu otherwise it will go to Windows directly without showing the menu. What is the issue here? How can I get the menu without pressing F9?

Comment: Does F9 show some kind of bios/efi boot-selection or does it show grub? Usually dual-boot setups with linux do use grub as boot-manager - which should always appear (even if its configured for a short display time)

Comment: F9 shows me the Boot Manager..

Comment: "Boot Manager" can refer to a lot of things.  Make a picture.

Comment: Boot Manager shows up where in I have these options to choose 1. OS boot manager (UEFI) -Windows Boot Manager 2. OS Boot Manager (UEFI) - ubuntu 3. Boot from EFI file 4. Notebook Hard Drive and when I choose one of the first two options i go to the GNU GRUB where there is menu showing Ubuntu and Windows and Memtest and so on.

Comment: Yes, this is your firmware (BIOS/EFI) showing you that.  It has nothing to do with either Windows or Ubuntu.   So, if you choose either (1=Windows, 2=Ubuntu) it gives you GRUB?  So what is the problem?  It is in GRUB you traditionally choose the OS you want to start.
If you want this boot manager, you need to configure this in your BIOS/EFI and the option might  not exist. As I said in my answer.  I cite myself: `Best chance you have is to look into your BIOS/EFI Setup (Typically F1, F2, F10 or Esc) and look for an option that says "Always show boot menu". That option does not always exist.`

Comment: That option is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds as if you have two disks in your machine, and are using the BIOS/EFI to switch between the boot disk.  The is something not controlled by Ubuntu or Windows.

Best chance you have is to look into your BIOS/EFI Setup (Typically `F1`, `F2`, `F10` or `Esc`) and look for an option that says "Always show boot menu".  That option does not always exist.

You can change the boot order in the BIOS/EFI, so that it boots straight to Ubuntu instead.

Finally, you can install GRUB on the boot disk and it will give you a menu to choose.  Most likely, this is already the case if you set your boot disk to your Ubuntu disk.

---

(Edit: Based on discussion in comments)

The boot order often must be changed with the `+` and `-` keys or `F5` and `F6` within the appropriate menu of your BIOS/EFI.

Comment: I dont want to change the boot order. I just want the direct menu while booting and not by manually pressing F9

Comment: Change it for trial and see whether GRUB comes up, instead of dismissing my answer?

Comment: No it is not helping

Comment: So, let me get this straight.  If you do not push F9, you don't get GRUB?

Comment: Yeah it directly boots Windows OS

Comment: And if you change the boot order in BIOS/EFI to Ubuntu?  It goes straight into Ubuntu?

Comment: I am not able to change the order in BIOS

Comment: You should be able to get into the BIOS/EFI setup.  Please refer to your computers manual to find out how.

Comment: Yeah I am able to get to the BIOS setup and that boot order is also there but I am not able to change it

Comment: Is this a company laptop with locked firmware?

Comment: no this is my personal laptop

Comment: Unless you have a really crappy BIOS/EFI, this is standard functionality.  Often you must change the order with `+` and `-` keys or `F5` and `F6` within the appropriate menu.  There is no way anyone can help you with this.  Each and every BIOS/EFI is different.
Good luck.

Comment: Hey I got it...I just changed the boot order. I used F5 and it worked. Now I dont need to press F9 any longer. Thanks.

Comment: It does say so on the bottom of the screen, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Check if there's a boot option "OS boot manager" in your UEFI (I assume it's UEFI and not Legacy). If there is, give it highest boot priority.

Comment: How do I see this?

Comment: See boot order in your "BIOS" (UEFI).

Comment: It is not helping

Comment: The it seems you installed Ubuntu in Legacy boot mode instead of UEFI. I'm not 100% sure how to fix it but you should find it easily on AskUbuntu (I don't want to copy-paste someone else's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Press F10 . Go to boot options then go to boot manager. Change your first priority to ubuntu. Rather than windows . Then press F10 then again F10